# Angular: How to redirect to a given url if variable is present in localStorage?

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-ui-router

When I load the application, the default site language is English. However, when I change language to say French,I am storing a variable in local storage that contains the path of that specific site-locale. I want that next time if I load the application, it should check to see if my stored variable in the local Storage has a value and redirect me to that particular site-locale I choose earlier. Currently my implementation gives me an infinite loop such that when I load the application, it keeps on reloading without an stopping. **WHAT COULD I BE DOING WRONG?**
Here is what I have done:

```js
// header component
export class HeaderComponent implements OnInit {

  languages = [{
      code: 'en-US',
      label: 'English'
    },
    {
      code: 'am',
      label: 'Amharic'
    },
  ];

  constructor(
    @Inject(LOCALE_ID) public localeId: string,
    @Inject(APP_BASE_HREF) public baseHref: string,
    public location: Location
  ) {}

  cacheLocalePreference() {
    if (this.localeId === 'en-US') {
      localStorage.setItem('localePath', location.href);
    } else if (this.localeId === 'am') {
      localStorage.setItem('localePath', location.href);
    }
  }
}

// index component
export class IndexComponent implements OnInit {

  localePath: any;
  defaultPathDev: string;
  defaultPathLive: string;

  constructor(
    public route: Router,
    public location: Location,
    @Inject(LOCALE_ID) public localeId: string,
    @Inject(APP_BASE_HREF) public baseHref: string
  ) {
    this.defaultPathDev = 'http://localhost:4200';
    this.defaultPathLive = 'http://localhost/inibla';
    this.localePath = localStorage.getItem('localePath');
    console.log('baseHref', baseHref);
    console.log('localeID', localeId);
    console.log('localePath', this.localePath);
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    if (this.localePath !== null) {
      if (location.href === this.localePath) {
        return;
      } else {
        window.location.href = this.localePath;
      }
    } else {
      window.location.href = this.defaultPathDev;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: can you ```console.log(location.href)``` and ```console.log(this.localePath)``` in the ```ngOnInit``` please?

Comment: @user3740359 console(location.href) gives  this http://localhost:4200 when I load the app for the first time while console.log(this.localePath) is null on the first time load otherwise after change the language the consoles change to http://localhost:4200/en-US if it is english that was choosen or http://localhost:4200/fr for french

Comment: is ```location.href``` on the second run still ```localhost:4200``` ?

Comment: @user3740359 Without changing the locale yes if I reload the it is still localhost:4200 otherwise it appends the locale id to te url if a language is selected